# Perl: Where am I going wrong with postfix/prefix precedence?

Tags: perl, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

The following fragment shows a simple n-perline output procedure.

Two cases are shown, one using prefix ++, the other postfix ++, in a boolean expression.

Since '++' has higher precedence than '==', I expected the results to be the same, but they are not: one does 5 per line, the other 6.

```
use English;

my @arr = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6);
my $perline = 5;
my $ndone = 0;

for(@arr) {
    print "  $ARG";
    if(++$ndone == $perline) {
        $ndone = 0;
        print "\n";
    }
}

print "\n---\n";

my $perline = 5;
my $ndone = 0;

for(@arr) {
    print "  $ARG";
    if($ndone++ == $perline) {
        $ndone = 0;
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9  8
  7  6
---
  1  2  3  4  5  6
  7  8  9  8  7  6
```

Comment: Missing `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Don't `use English`, it makes code harder to read.

Comment: Your code can be simplified to: `my $i = 0; print ++$i, "\n"; my $j = 0; print $j++, "\n";`

Comment: @melpomene To be fair: that isn't the equivalent of the whole code. But it shows the difference between `++$i` and `$i++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not about precedence of operations but about what prefix and postfix ++ return. From perldoc perlop:

> "++" and "--" work as in C. That is, if placed before a variable, they
>       increment or decrement the variable by one before returning the value, and
>       if placed after, increment or decrement after returning the value.

Essentially you could define these as functions:

```
sub prefix_plusplus {
    $_[0] = $_[0] + 1;   # increment value
    return $_[0];        # returns value after increment
}

sub postfix_plusplus {
    my $before = $_[0];
    $_[0] = $_[0] + 1;  # increment value
    return $before;     # returns value before increment
}


my $x = my $y = 5;
printf "%d,%d\n", prefix_plusplus($x), postfix_plusplus($y);   #  6,5
printf "%d,%d\n", $x, $y;                                      #  6,6

# and same thing with the ++ operand
$x = $y = 5;
printf "%d,%d\n", ++$x, $y++;                                  #  6,5
printf "%d,%d\n", $x, $y;                                      #  6,6
```